# Checking two std::map with some shared keys if overlapping keys map to the same values

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, c++17, std

I have two maps that might have some overlapping keys. I want to check if, on those keys, the corresponding values agree. What is the best (fastest) way to implement this?

I have a rudimentary implementation using the insert function below:

```
bool mergable(map<set<int>, vector<int>> map1, map<set<int>, vector<int>> map2) {
    map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());
    map2.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
    if (map1 == map2) {
        return true;
    }
    cout << "Dictionaries not mergable" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

For this implementation, I have to pass copies of my maps to avoid modifying them. I'm sure that there's a faster way to do this. For me, one map is usually smaller than the other, but both have at most around 20 keys.

Comment: Observe that maps store keys in strict weak ordering. So, with a pair of beginning/ending iterators to both maps you have two sorted sequences. I would think that every computer science algorithm course (I hope) explains how to iterate over the combined pair of sequence in `O(n)` complexity to identify all keys in common. Do that, and compare the values each time two keys in common are found. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The easy way

> I want to check if, on those keys, the corresponding values agree.

You can implement that idea much more directly.
Simply go through all those keys the maps have in common and check if the values are the same.

[`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is quite convenient in this case.

```cpp
bool mergable(const map<set<int>, vector<int>> &map1,
              const map<set<int>, vector<int>> &map2)
{
    return all_of(map1.begin(), map1.end(), [&map2](const auto& pair) {
        auto it = map2.find(pair.first);
        // note: the it == map2.end() part means that keys which aren't found
        //       in both maps don't have to be equal; only the common keys must be.
        return it == map2.end() || *it == pair.second;
    };
}
```

This solution is amortized O(n log n)<sup>(1)</sup> because iterating over a `std::map` is amortized O(n), and the look-up through `.find()` is O(log n).

<sup>(1)</sup> ignoring the cost of the `std::vector` comparisons

### The hard way

With some extra work, you can squeeze out a faster solution.
Since you're working with `std::map`s, the the key-value pairs are ordered, and you can come up with an O(n) solution.

In essence, you perform something like a `std::set_union` except that you don't output anything, you just return early if equivalent keys don't have equal values.

```cpp
using Iter = map<set<int>, vector<int>>::const_iterator;

bool mergable(Iter first1, Iter last1,
              Iter first2, Iter last2)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        // this may be done faster in C++20 with a three-way comparison
        if (first1->first < first2->first)
            ++first1;
        else if (first2->first < first1->first)
            ++first2;
        // if neither key is lower, the keys are equivalent, and
        // the values must be equal
        else if (first1->second != first2->second)
            return false;
        else {
            ++first1;
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    // Finished either range; the rest doesn't matter
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that maps are sorted. This means you can iterate over both maps at the same time. If the keys are different, then you move to the next element of the map with the "lesser" key, to "catch up" with the other map. If the keys are identical, you check the value and then move to the next element of both maps.

In code, something like this:

```cpp
using MyMap = map<set<int>, vector<int>>;

bool mergable(MyMap const& a, MyMap const& b) {
    auto aIt = a.begin();
    auto bIt = b.begin();

    while (aIt != a.end() && bIt != b.end()) {
        if (aIt->first < bIt->first) {
            // a's key is less than b's key -> move to a's next entry
            ++aIt;
        } else if (bIt->first < aIt->first) {
            // b's key is less than a's key -> move to b's next entry
            ++bIt;
        } else {
            // the keys are equal -> make sure the values are equal...
            if (aIt->second != bIt->second) {
                return false; // value mismatch -> not mergable
            }
            // ...and advance to next entry of a and b
            ++aIt;
            ++bIt;
        }
    }

    return true; // no mismatches found -> maps are mergable
}
```

This doesn't require copying anything and should run in **O(max(n, m))**, where **n** and **m** are the number of elements in the maps.

Comment: Thanks! It seems this and the other comment under "The hard way" are the same solution, and probably what I will go for

Comment: @bottledcaps Yes, they're the same. When I started writing my answer, the other answer didn't have that part yet.